# how to bind value in my custom stencil component to the backend model in my asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages, stenciljs

At very beginning I was using the following code to pass value to my backend.

```
<input asp-for="Input.Email" type="email" class="form-control"/>
<label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
<span asp-validation-for="Input.Email"></span>
```

Which `Input` is my backend model. But now I'd like to use a new input tag customized by stencil js which does't receive `asp-for` attribute, which looks like this.

```
<myinput label ="Email" name="Email" id="Email"></myinput>
<span asp-validation-for="Input.Email"></span>
```

How could I pass the value to the backend model?